# Using Ubuntu 12.04 live from USB stick first time user id and password

Tags: password, username

I just created a USB flash drive with 12.04 live.  When it starts up it asks for a user id and password.  What are they?

Answer (score 1):

The default username is **ubuntu**, and the password is **blank** on an Ubuntu LiveUSB.

Answer (score 0):

userid is yourname and ,password is the password you have created at the time of installation.

Comment: I have not installed it yet.  I am using the try before installation option.

Comment: Sorry, that did not work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: use "adduser username" to add username then provide a password, and again use the username you have created and the password you provided before..

Comment: Neither of these suggestions has helped.  Any other ideas?